# Add external Css/Js files to Typo3 11 custom backend extension

Tags: javascript, css, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

I am trying to add my own CSS and JS files to my view in my custom typo3 backend extension.

Here is the folder layout:
[project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf3zR.jpg)

And here is the code I am using for the View New.html:

```
<f:section name="HeaderAssets">
    <f:asset.css identifier="css" href="EXT:plugin/Resources/Public/Css/Styles.css" />
    <f:asset.css identifier="css">
        .foo { color: black; }
    </f:asset.css>

    <f:asset.script identifier="js" src="EXT:plugin/Resources/Public/JavaScript/ApiConnect.js" />
    <f:asset.script identifier="js">
        alert('hello world');
    </f:asset.script>
</f:section>

//I also tried this and it did nothing

<f:be.pageRenderer pageTitle="title"
                   includeCssFiles="{0: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'Public/Css/Styles.css\')}'}"
                   includeJsFiles="{0: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'Public/JavaScript/ApiConnect.js\')}'}"
/>
```

Is there something wrong with the path that I am using? I feel like it should not be this complicated :D Inside the CSS and Js are basic body color changes and an alert for testing purposes. nothing fancy (yet).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According to the docs example, the second snippet should use another syntax for paths: `includeCssFiles="{0: 'EXT:my_ext/Resources/Public/Css/Stylesheet.css'}"`. https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Be/PageRenderer.html

Comment: @JulianHofmann this is also not working.....

Answer (score 0):

According to the description in the ResourceViewHelper.php, your path-argument needs to start `relative to Public resource directory of the extension`

So this should do the trick:

```
<f:be.pageRenderer pageTitle="title"
       includeCssFiles="{0: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'Css/Styles.css\')}'}"
       includeJsFiles="{0: '{f:uri.resource(path:\'JavaScript/ApiConnect.js\')}'}"
/>
```